# Google closure compiler error "Variable COMPILED first declared in {SyntheticVarsDeclar}"

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

When using the Google closure compiler to try and compile a load of closure dependencies taken from their [editor demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html) (no external code) using `calcdeps.py` I get the following error when then running the compiler on the produced code (which runs fine):

```
 {SyntheticVarsDeclar}: ERROR - Variable COMPILED first declared in {SyntheticVarsDeclar}
```

The variable COMPILED is only used in 2 places within the file that calculated dependencies produces and isn't declared anywhere in there. The only place I see it declared is in base.js.

Comment: Could you provide the 2 lines where COMPILED is used/declard?

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a bug in the closure compiler. Apparently it has already been fixed. You should download a current version of the closure compiler.

There is a closed [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=22#c1) for this issue in the closure-compiler issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it at the start and use this [tag](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#tag-define) like this:

```
/**
* @define {boolean} Overridden to true by the compiler when --closure_pass
*                   or --mark_as_compiled is specified.
*/
var COMPILED = false;
```

I'm almost sure that it will fix the problem, in fact I even think that you don't need the tag. Also try downloading latest compiler or compile it from svn because there was [suspiciously similar bug](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=17) reported earlier and it got fixed.